# Python Loop Assistance

Tags: python, loops, csv

I'm new with Python and needing help for some problem with loops.

I have a CSV file named test1.csv and there are two columns (Fruit and Fruit_Container)

[Screenshot of the CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syJZo.png)
and here is my code:

```
import csv

def fruits():
    with open('test1.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(f'Fruits: {row["Fruit"]}')

def fruit_container():
    with open('test1.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(f'The fruits are: {row["Fruit"]} and they are placed in a {row["Fruit_Container"]}')

fruits()
fruit_container()
```

The result I'm getting is the following:

```
Fruits: Apple
Fruits: Banana
Fruits: Orange
The fruits are: Apple and they are placed in a Crate
The fruits are: Banana and they are placed in a Crate
The fruits are: Orange and they are placed in a Crate
```

But the Result that I want is as follow:

```
Fruits: Apple
Fruits: Banana
Fruits: Orange

The fruits are: 
Apple and they are placed in a Crate
Banana and they are placed in a Crate
Orange and they are placed in a Crate
```

How can I achieve this output?

Regards
Denis

Comment: Move the printing of "The fruits are: " (only those word!) to before the loop, and it will be printed just once.

Comment: in fruit_container() function , "The fruits are:" should be outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `The fruits are:` outside the `for` loop :

```
def fruit_container():
    with open('test1.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        print("The fruits are: ")
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(f'{row["Fruit"]} and they are placed in a {row["Fruit_Container"]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve the desired results:

**Definitions:**

```
import csv
def fruits():
    with open('test1.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        fruits_list = []
        fruits_container_list = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            fruits_list.append(row["Fruit"])
            fruits_container_list.append(row["Fruits_Container"])
        return fruits_list, fruits_container_list
```

**Method Call:**

```
fruits_list, fruits_container_list  = fruits()
for index in range(0, len(fruits_list)):
        print('Fruits: {}'.format(fruits_list[index]))  
print('\nThe fruits are: ')
for index in range(0, len(fruits_list)):
        print('{} and they are placed in a {}'.format(fruits_list[index], fruits_container_list[index]))
```

`return fruits_list` and `return fruits_container_list` are two return statements of list objects to the call. This helps in streamlining the process. The `for index in range(0, len(fruits_list))` iterates through the lists to produce a synchronized output. Happy Coding!